# Descriptive stats from stat.desc() is in scientific notation form

Tags: r, scientific-notation

Lets say I have a data frame "example" of a bunch of random integers

```
example <- data.frame(Column1 = floor(runif(7, min = 1000, max = 7000)), 
                      column2 = floor(runif(7, min = 12000, max = 70000)))
```

I want to get a summary of the descriptive statistics of these columns so I use

```
stat.desc(example)
```

But the output of the descriptive statistics is in scientific notation form. I know I can do:

```
format(stat.desc(example), scientific = FALSE)
```

And it will convert it to non-scientific notation, but why is scientific notation the default output mode?

Comment: You need to indicate where `stat.desc` is from. [This?](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/basic_desc.htm)

Comment: Yes sorry that is where stat.desc is from

Comment: Here is a reference: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/basic_desc.htm

Answer (score 4):

It is created that way. However, you can set the options:

```
options(scipen=100)
options(digits=3)
stat.desc(example)
```

This will produce output as you like without converting to decimals afterward. I've included rounding as it will likely be 6-7 digits without the rounding option. This would give you 3 decimal places and no scientific notation.

Comment: BethanyP, you are amazing. Thank you very much. I don't have enough reputation to upvote you but thank you